# Why can't I use toFixed on an HTML input object's value?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML input element and I'm trying to force a single decimal place into the input after the user changes the value.  So, let's say the user enters "4", I run this code:

```
this.value = this.value.toFixed(1)
```

but then I get a JavaScript error saying "Object 4 has no method 'toFixed'".

It seems like JavaScript is trying to process a literal as a Number and failing but, er, why? And how do I avoid it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`this.value` is a `String` when you get it from an input element. You need to cast it to a number before you can use a number's methods on it:

```
this.value = Number(this.value).toFixed(1);
```

Alternatively you can use the unary `+` operator to cast the string to a number:

```
this.value (+this.value).toFixed(1);
```

If you need to remove string suffixes, then you could use `parseFloat`:

```
this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(1);
```

However, it's worth noting that `parseFloat` *does not* handle hexadecimal formats while casting to `Number` *does*:

```
this.value = +'0xF'; //15
this.value = parseFloat('0xF'); //0
```

Comment: Thanks. That did it (though I alto took Ben Blank's "parseFloat" advice below).  I guess I was used to JavaScript being more flexible about type casting...

Comment: It's very flexible, but it can only look at the methods associated with the current object type. `toFixed` is useful if you need a specific precision, `parseFloat`/`parseInt` are useful for type/value conversion.

Comment: — I think you misunderstood my suggestion; I'm advocating `this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(1);`

Answer (score 3):

convert to a Number first,

```
this.value = Number(this.value).toFixed(1);
```

`this.value` is a String, and a string does not have the `toFixed` method.

Comment: Using the `Number` constructor is overkill for this; `parseFloat` is probably the better option.

Comment: @Ben Blank, `Number()` isn't being used as a constructor, it's being used to cast. unlike server scripts, JS tends not to have as much of a performance requirement, and @Jeff Chausse did specify that a certain precision was desired, so casting to a number would be appropriate in this instance. If a numeric representation was desired without any precision, `parseFloat` would definitely be the way to go.

Comment: @zzzzBov — Whether it's being *used* as a constructor isn't the issue; `parseFloat` is designed for the specific purpose of converting a string to a floating-point number and so many JS engines optimize it as such (e.g. by passing it directly to the underlying C function).  `Number` doesn't benefit from such optimizations because it has a broader scope and must run through a number of checks first.  I'm not sure what you mean by "without any precision"… this `Number` call will result in a call to the same internal method that `parseFloat` does.