# Uncaught TypeError: Object 5229d8fff4ae7a3803000023 has no method 'toFixed'

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views, backgrid

Here is my code snippet :

```
    json.iddd = ~~(json.id);
    console.log(typeof(json.iddd)); //shows number

    new ResponseTabView(json.iddd); // backbone view
```

inside the view i am calling:

```
this.grid = new Backgrid.Grid({body : this.body, collection :this.collection, columns: this.columns});
```

I get the following error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object 5229d8fff4ae7a3803000023 has no method 'toFixed'
```

How to get rid of it?

Comment: can you print `json.iddd` here?

Comment: json.iddd results into 0. help me out of it. I want to convert the json.id that is into string into the number type. and also do not want the value of json.id to get changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Abhilash said , You are using `toFixed()` on `string` type Object that will surely result into error
*`Object xyz has no method toFixed`*.

`toFixed` is method of `number Object` not string.

Here is a reference table for you

**Number Object Methods**

```
toExponential(x)    Converts a number into an exponential notation
toFixed(x)          Formats a number with x numbers of digits after the decimal point
toPrecision(x)      Formats a number to x length
toString()          Converts a Number object to a string
valueOf()           Returns the primitive value of a Number object
```

So you need to parse the string into integer using `parstInt()` or `parseFloat()`

```
parseInt(json.iddd).toFixed();   Or
parseFloat(json.iddd).toFixed();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the parameters passed to the `Backgrid.Grid`, one parameter needs to be of `Number` type. But the parameter that you are passing is of 'String' type.

`String` object doesn't have a `toFixed()` for you to use. Hence the error.

Please `console.log` the `typoof` each parameter and also read the docs of Backgrid to see what parameter needs to be of `Number` type.

Cheers!

Comment: so how do i convert string into number in javascript. I have json.id into string and and want to convert into number.

Comment: Refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330420/why-cant-i-use-tofixed-on-an-html-input-objects-value