# How to use .toFixed() from an input field

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to understand why I can't get `.toFixed()` to work in my code. I've tried different variations but something is missing.

I get the following error upon running the code.

> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).value.toFixed is not
>   a function

My Code:

```
<input type="number" id="num1">
<p>+</p>
<input type="number" id="num2">
<p>=</p>
<p id="result"></p>
<br>
<button id="submit" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>

<script>
  function calculate(){
    const a = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    const b = document.getElementById("num2").value;

    let finalAnswer = a.toFixed(2) + b.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = finalAnswer;
    console.log(a);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: toFixed is on a number, however when you get the value of an input, it will be a string. Try converting to a number first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I use toFixed on an HTML input object's value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330420/why-cant-i-use-tofixed-on-an-html-input-objects-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toFixed` is defined in `Number` as you [can see in the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) therefore you must first convert the input values to numbers before using it.

For that you can use the `Number` constructor passing it the text to convert:

```
let myNumber = Number(someString);
```

After that you can output the result with `toFixed()` which gives you a `string` with as many digits after the decimal point as the number you passed to it:

```
console.log(myNumber.toFixed(2));
```

Taking all of this into consideration you can change your code to:

```js
function calculate() {
  const a = document.getElementById("num1").value;
  const b = document.getElementById("num2").value;

  //Convert both inputs to Number's before adding them
  let finalAnswer = Number(a) + Number(b); 

  //toFixed only here when you need to output it
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = finalAnswer.toFixed(2); 
  console.log(a);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="num1">
<p>+</p>
<input type="number" id="num2">
<p>=</p>
<p id="result"></p>
<br>
<button id="submit" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The .toFixed() is a method for numbers. When you get the value from a input, it is a string. Therefore you have to convert it to a number. 
You can convert to number with: 
`Number()`
So, your code should look something like this:

> const a = Number(document.getElementById("num1").value); const b = Number(document.getElementById("num2").value);

Answer (score 0):

That's because your input gets evaluated as a string and not as a number, this is one of the multiple ways i'd solve it:

```
const a = document.getElementById("num1").value - 0;
const b = document.getElementById("num2").value - 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use step for float range ether.You cant use:
`<input type="number" step=any`
To float I recomend to setting 0.01.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).