# Round a number to 2 decimal places JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have

```
oninput="
    price_<?php echo esc_attr( $range_slider_id ); ?>.value=parseFloat(<?php echo esc_attr( $range_price_id ); ?>)*parseFloat(<?php echo esc_attr( $range_slider_id ); ?>.value); "
```

how to round price_~.value two decimal places?

I have on output:

```
<output id="price_range_5e5851cd67084" for="range_5e5851cd67084">43.199999999999996</output>
```

I have tried to add .toFixed(2) and .round(2) .. but it doesn't help...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Round to at most 2 decimal places (only if necessary)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary)

Comment: [*Math.round*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) rounds to the nearest integer, second or additional arguments are ignored. [*number.toFixed*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) returns a string. Please post valid javascript (e.g. what the PHP generates) or tag as PHP. Also sample input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: worse case, whatever the language, you can always use a standard round with something like (round(x*100))/100... with an extra conversion to int if the round didn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

use `toFixed(2)`

such as

```
oninput="
    price_<?php echo esc_attr( $range_slider_id ); ?>.value=parseFloat(<?php echo esc_attr( $range_price_id ).toFixed(2); ?>)*parseFloat(<?php echo esc_attr( $range_slider_id ); ?>.value).toFixed(2); "
```

Answer (score 1):

found solution from this topic [Why can't I use toFixed on an HTML input object's value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330420/why-cant-i-use-tofixed-on-an-html-input-objects-value) the final result:

```
price_<?php echo esc_attr( $range_slider_id ); ?>.value=Number(<?php echo esc_attr( $range_price_id ); ?>)*Number(<?php echo esc_attr( $range_slider_id ); ?>.value); price_<?php echo esc_attr( $range_slider_id ); ?>.value=Number(price_<?php echo esc_attr( $range_slider_id ); ?>.value).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is just to display the number you can use:

```js
number.toLocaleString('en', {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2})
```

You can also replace 'en' with your preferred locale 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Locale